# Code for the manual of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Does anyone know the code of [this manual for `tcolorbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox)? Actually I wanted to compile it in MiKTeX to learn more about `tcolorbox`.

Comment: The source code is on ctan http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.tex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On TeX Live the source for manual is included in the `doc` tree:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/
```

If I ask for `ls` on this directory, I get

```
Basilica_5.png                      tcolorbox.doc.intro.tex
CHANGES                             tcolorbox.doc.listings.tex
README                              tcolorbox.doc.magazine.tex
lichtspiel.jpg                      tcolorbox.doc.picturecredits.tex
tcolorbox-example.pdf               tcolorbox.doc.quickref.tex
tcolorbox-example.tex               tcolorbox.doc.raster.tex
tcolorbox.doc.abstract.tex          tcolorbox.doc.recording.tex
tcolorbox.doc.bib                   tcolorbox.doc.references.tex
tcolorbox.doc.breakable.tex         tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty
tcolorbox.doc.coremacros.tex        tcolorbox.doc.s_snippet.sty
tcolorbox.doc.coreoptions.tex       tcolorbox.doc.sidebyside.tex
tcolorbox.doc.documentation.tex     tcolorbox.doc.skins.tex
tcolorbox.doc.external.tex          tcolorbox.doc.technical.tex
tcolorbox.doc.filling.tex           tcolorbox.doc.theorems.tex
tcolorbox.doc.fitting.tex           tcolorbox.doc.verbatim.tex
tcolorbox.doc.graphics.tex          tcolorbox.doc.xparse.tex
tcolorbox.doc.hooks.tex             tcolorbox.pdf
tcolorbox.doc.index.tex             tcolorbox.tex
tcolorbox.doc.initoptions.tex
```

The main file is `tcolorbox.tex`.

If you have the `doc` tree on MiKTeX, the files should be available (just find out where the tree is rooted).

You can also find them on CTAN at

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox

Comment: What does it mean to have `doc` tree on MiKTeX?

Comment: @user170039 I'm no expert with MiKTeX, but I believe it has the doc files somewhere, look for the main directory of MiKTeX and find a folder called `doc`.

Comment: @user170039 MiKTeX keeps the doc files under `<miktex>\doc\latex\tcolorbox` where `<miktex>` is the installation directory e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex`